# Index values to a vector with numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have created a vector of zeros called **Qc_vector** (18 rows x 1 column).

I have created another vector called **s_vector** (6 rows x 1 column) that is generated each time by a for loop within the range **ingreso_datos**, that is, for this example it is generated 5 times.

I have also created a list called **indices** that is generated for each iteration of the loop, these indices tell me the row number to which I should index the values from **s_vector** to **Qc_vector**

**PROBLEM**

When trying to do this I get the following error: *ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (6,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (6,1)*

For element 6 of the matrix **ingreso_datos**, the **indices** are: [1,2,3,4,5,6]

For the end of the loop, that is, for element number 5 **s_vector** it looks like this:

[s_vector for element 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2r8v.png)

[Qc_vector indexed, how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xLY5.png)

```
import numpy as np

#            Element   1(i)   2(i)   3(i)   1(j)   2(j)    3(j)    x(i)    y(i)    x(j)    y(j)  | W(kg/m)   Axis(kg/m)
#             [Col0]  [Col1] [Col2] [Col3] [Col4] [Col5]  [Col6]  [Col7]  [Col8] [Col9]  [Col10] | [Col11]   [Col12]

ingreso_datos = [[ 1,   13,    14,    15,     7,    8,      9,       0,      0,      0,    2.5,        0,       0],
                 [ 2,   16,    17,    18,    10,   11,       12,     4.5,      0,    4.5,    2.5,        0,       0],
                 [ 3,    7,     8,     9,     1,    2,        3,     4.5,      0,    4.5,    2.5,        0,       0],
                 [ 4,   10,    11,    12,     4,    5,        6,     4.5,      0,    4.5,    2.5,        0,       0],
                 [ 5,    7,     8,     9,    10,   11,       12,     4.5,      0,    4.5,    2.5,    -2200,       0]]


Qc_vector = np.zeros((12,1))       # Vector de zeros 

for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)): 

    indices = [] 
    indices.append([ingreso_datos[i][0], ingreso_datos[i][1], ingreso_datos[i][2], ingreso_datos[i][3],
                    ingreso_datos[i][4], ingreso_datos[i][5], ingreso_datos[i][6]])   

    for row in indices:
        indices = np.array(row[1:])

    L = np.sqrt((ingreso_datos[i][9]-ingreso_datos[i][7])**2+(ingreso_datos[i][10]-ingreso_datos[i][8])**2)
    lx = (ingreso_datos[i][9]-ingreso_datos[i][7])/L
    ly = (ingreso_datos[i][10]-ingreso_datos[i][8])/L            
    w = ingreso_datos[i][11]
    ad = ingreso_datos[i][12]

    s_vector = np.array([ad*L/2,    w*L/2,   (w*L**2)/12,   ad*L/2,     w*L/2,   (-w*L**2)/12])    # s_vector


    Qc_vector[np.ix_(indices)] = s_vector # Indexing
```

Comment: Your previous question in which I suggested using `ix_`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60936223/add-multiple-arrays-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Qc_vector` is (18,1).

```
indices = [ingreso_datos[i][0], ingreso_datos[i][1], ingreso_datos[i][2], ingreso_datos[i][3], ingreso_datos[i][4], ingreso_datos[i][5], ingreso_datos[i][6]])
```

or simply:

```
indices = [ingreso_datos[i,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]]
```

followed by:

```
for row in indices:
    indices = np.array(row[1:])
```

which is just

```
ingreso_datos[i,[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

`s_vector` is a 6 element array, shape (6,)

In:

```
Qc_vector[np.ix_(indices)] = s_vector
```

you don't need `ix_`.  In my previous answer I suggested:

```
master_matrix[np.ix_(indices,indices)] ==little_matrix
```

as a way of doing the indexing for all rows, not just one at a time.

I think your assignment can be simplified to

```
Qc_vector[indices, 0] = s_vector
```

That way there's a shape (6,) array on both sides.

I have a feeling you are still trying to write this code by copying other people's code, without understanding what is happening, or why they suggest things.

---

or define `Qc_vector` with shape (18,) rather than (18,1).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment and for your observation, I will reinforce the logic of this, my first language with exercises proposed by python cookbook.
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix if you don't want to bother too much would be to use [numpy.reshape()](https://www.w3resource.com/numpy/manipulation/reshape.php).
This way you can manage the shape mismatch.